# Kate auto indents specific keywords mysteriously

Tags: kate

I design a custom syntax highlighter of a custom language for Kate.

To begin with a template, did I use the xml file from a similar language as a starting point.

I removed both "indenter" and "style" specifications from the xml file (which would otherwise eventually overwrite my default setting in Kate) and I did set "None" in the Kate settings.

Still, the keywords "else" and "catch" get indented whenever there is space left on the right handside of the keyword. If there is already text, the indendation does not happen.

It happens with placing these keywords at `<list name="cflow">` and `<list name="cflow_eb">` and `<list name="keywords">`.
It does also happen if I delete the keyword entirely from the xml specification.

But it does not happen with another language, only with my own definition and that of the original language.

What is going on?

I attach a link to a video. I am currently on Wayland, and the screen recorder there are still in early development, please excuse the subpar quality. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nIaDwNZzz2s

Language file: https://paste.ee/p/kbisC

Comment: Please add your code to the question itself, not on an external site.

Comment: @Progman Body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 34063.

Comment: Truncate the file down to the actual problem, see [mcve].